# What if an interesting question found somewhere but is not open to accept new answers

Tags: discussion

I was surfing web and found a good philosophical question in a Physics forum (and was not open to new answers) which actually belonged here. Since I want to answer it as one of those who participate, it doesn't make sense to do so.

Since Philosophy website is young there should be similar situations for other members. What to do in such situations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your concern fully (esp. "Since I want to answer it as one of those who participate, it doesn't make sense to do so." [to do *what*?]), but in general you are free to ask any question here as long as it is on-topic, regardless of whether it can be found elsewhere on the internet. It is generally bad form if you post the same question to multiple *StackExchange* websites simultaneously, but that's a separate issue.

**Bottom line: If it pertains to philosophy, is reasonably answerable, and is not a poll, it is welcome here. :)**

Comment: I meant it doesn't make sense to ask a question and then answer it yourself.

Comment: Actually that's fine, in fact it's [strongly encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). :)

Comment: It strikes me as sort of like commissioning yourself to write an article for SE. Not a bad idea at all, but I'd encourage those who want to do it to make sure they are asking a question clearly and answering the question in a correspondingly clear way.

Comment: @Dennis: I felt same to asked the question. Still waiting for a good answer from others to accept it, otherwise answer it myself.

Answer (score 2):

You can, as stoicfury♦ says in his answer, ask a similar question here and then answer it. I'd like to add another thing: **migration**.

Migration can be done by moderators when a post actually belongs on another site. It would look like [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/60250/21428). More information can be found [here on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32490/205264).

You can just flag the post for moderator's attention and ask for a migration to philosophy.